# eslint: no-case-declaration - unexpected lexical declaration in case block

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the better way to update state in this context inside a reducer?

```
case DELETE_INTEREST:
    let deleteInterests = state.user.interests;
    let index = deleteInterests.findIndex(i => i == action.payload);
    deleteInterests.splice(index, 1);
    return { ...state, user: { ...state.user, interests: deleteInterests } };
```

ESLint doesn't like let statements inside case blocks inside a reducer, getting:

> eslint: no-case-declaration - unexpected lexical declaration in case
>   block

Comment: `deleteInterests` is still a reference to the array in state so you're still mutating. Clone the list before splicing.

Comment: Use `{}` for the `case DELETE_INTEREST` in `switch` to get rid of this lint issue as per, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-case-declarations

Answer (score 504, accepted):

> ESLint doesn't like let statements inside case blocks inside a
> reducer, Why?

This is discouraged because it results in the variable being in scope outside of your current `case`. By using a block you limit the scope of the variable to that block.

Use `{}` to create the block scope with case, like this:

```
case DELETE_INTEREST: {
    let .....
    return (...)
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
function withOutBraces() { 
  switch(1){
    case 1: 
      let a=10; 
      console.log('case 1', a); 
    case 2: 
      console.log('case 2', a)
  } 
}

function withBraces() { 
  switch(1){
    case 1: {
      let a=10; 
      console.log('case 1', a); 
    }
    case 2: {
      console.log('case 2', a)
    }
  } 
}

console.log('========First Case ============')
withOutBraces()
console.log('========Second Case ============')
withBraces();
```

For deleting the element from array, use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), because [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will do the changes in original array. Write it like this:

```
case DELETE_INTEREST:
    let deleteInterests = state.user.interests;
    let newData = deleteInterests.filter(i => i !== action.payload);
    return { ...state, user: { ...state.user, interests: newData } };
```

Comment: Why, though? :)

Comment: From what I understood, if you declare a variable inside a `case` block without scoping it with `{}` your variable will be available in the switch block but will only be assigned in that case block (there's a risk it won't be declared if it doesn't go through that case) https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-case-declarations

Answer (score 27):

try to encapsulate the  inside the case with {}
like this look simple example

```
      case EnumCartAction.DELETE_ITEM: {
           const filterItems = state.cart.filter((item) => item._id !== action.payload)
           return {
                ...state,
                cart: filterItems
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy fix is to use brackets `{}` to encapsulate your case code.
If you're using `return` you might need to add `break` in some cases.