# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initialization. Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
        case 'ping' || 'Ping': {
      message.reply('PONG!');
    }

    break;


    // Kick



  case 'kick' || 'Kick':
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (user) {
          const member = message.guild.member(user);
          if (member) {
              member
                  .kick('Bad Boi')
                  .then(() => {
                      const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                          .setTitle(`Kick Results`)
                          .setColor(0xff0000)
                          .setDescription(`${user.tag} has been kicked!`)
                      message.channel.send(Embed);
                      const Embed3 = new MessageEmbed()
                      .setTitle(`Warn Results`)
                      .setColor(0xff0000)
                      .setDescription(`You have been banned! by ${message.author}`)
                      user.send(Embed3)
                  }).catch(err => {
                      message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
                      console.log(err);
                  })
          } else {
              const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(`Error`)
                  .setColor(0xff0000)
                  .setDescription('That user isn\'t in the guild!')
              message.channel.send(Embed);
          }
      } else {
          const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(`Error`)
              .setColor(0xff0000)
              .setDescription('That user isn\'t in the guild!')
          message.channel.send(Embed);
    }
    break;



    // Ban 



  case 'ban' || 'Ban':
      if (user) {
          const member = message.guild.member(user);
          if (member) {
              member
                  .ban({
                      reason: 'Bad Boi'
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                      const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                          .setTitle(`Ban Results`)
                          .setColor(0xff0000)
                          .setDescription(`${user.tag} has been banned!`)
                      message.channel.send(Embed);
                      message.channel.send(Embed);
                       const Embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                      .setTitle(`Warn Results`)
                      .setColor(0xff0000)
                      .setDescription(`You have been banned! by ${message.author}`)
                      user.send(Embed2)
                  }).catch(err => {
                      message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
                      console.log(err);
                  })
          } else {
              const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(`Error`)
                  .setColor(0xff0000)
                  .setDescription('That user isn\'t in the guild!')
              message.channel.send(Embed);
          }
      } else {
          const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(`Error`)
              .setColor(0xff0000)
              .setDescription('That user isn\'t in the guild!')
          message.channel.send(Embed);
    }

    break;


    // Warn

  case 'warn' || 'Warn': {
    if (user) {
      const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Warn Results`)
        .setColor(0xff0000)
        .setDescription(`${user.tag} has been warned!`)
      message.channel.send(Embed);
      const Embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Warn Results`)
        .setColor(0xff0000)
        .setDescription(`You have been warned! by ${message.author}`)
      user.send(Embed1)
    }
  }

  break;
  

  }
})
```

**I cant fix this error and its frustrating. Please help me it will be very appreciated. I only referenced the user once because it would break the other code however it was working fine before and now it's breaking.**

*Also if you do help please leave an explanation of my error so I don't need to ask again!*

*The warn-code block is failing*

Comment: Hi interesting, does the stack trace say which line is failung?

Comment: Yes, It is under the warn-code block that is failing

Comment: Either put `const user = message.mentions.users.first();` (in your kick command) outside of the `switch` block, or put braces (`{}`) around the kick and warn commands and put `const user = ...` in the warn command. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50753272/8289918) for info on lexical declarations (`const`, `let` etc.) in case blocks.